# Why do simulations just break sometimes?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I thought I was doing something wrong and breaking them, but here's how it goes. I bake a rigidbody simulation. I add a bit to the scene to make it look better. I delete the bake and bake again, and this time my objects get launched into the air way higher than they are supposed to be. So I undo a bunch to revert the changes I made, then when I bake yet again it's still broken. It seems to be randomly fixed sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried saving your file, exiting Blender, and restarting; after you delete the break?  Sometimes bugs will screw up the internal memory of a program in a way that only restarting fixes.

Comment: Pls upload your profile.Break ofter due to the cross of rigidbody,even you hide it,the cross will also take effect.